# How to mock a method which is part of a node-module using jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I need to mock a function when a button is clicked. The function is in a different file. This function use method from node_modules

```
import { recordCounter } from '../instrumentation/instrumentation';
<Button
  onClick={() => {
    recordCounter(`createTicketClicked`);
  }}
  text="Create Ticket"
/>
```

In the instrumentation.ts

```
import { newFederatedInstrumentation } from 'metrics';

const instance = newFederatedInstrumentation('myMetrics');
export const recordCounter = instance.recordCounter;
```

In the test I need to mock the method recordCounter to see whether this is been invoked and with what value?

Comment: You can use `jest.fn()` and `toBeCalledWith`.

Comment: Something similar?

`const recordCounter = jest.fn();
 expect(recordCounter).toHaveBeenCalledWith("createTicketClicked");
`
Throws me error.

Comment: Yes, like that. What error do you see?

Comment: I get an error.
`Expected: "createTicketClicked"
Number of calls: 0`

Comment: How do you "click" the button in the test? It would be helpful to see the test code.

Comment: This is my test code
`it('records counter when create ticket button is clicked', async () => {
    const recordCounter = jest.fn();
    const { getByTestId } = render(
      <FilterTickets />
    );
    const buttonId = getByTestId("createTicket");
    await userEvent.click(buttonId);
    expect(recordCounter).toHaveBeenCalledWith("ticketing-platform-plugin.createTicketClicked");
    });`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240832/discussion-between-magi-and-tromgy).

Answer (score 0):

You have two options for mocking this method in your case. The first option would be having an addition prop, where you supply the mocked method and have some expectations on that:

```
it('should call a method upon click', () => {
    const mockedMethod = jest.fn();     
    const { getByTestId } = render(<Component method={mockedMethod} />);    

    const button = getByTestId("button");     
    button.click();    

    expect(mockedMethod).toHaveBeenCalledWith("some-value");     
});
```

The second option would be to mock the method on module level and have pretty much the same expectations on that.

```
import { method } from "./method"

jest.mock("./method")

it('should call a method upon click', () => {  
    const { getByTestId } = render(<Component />);    

    const button = getByTestId("button");     
    button.click();    

    expect(method).toHaveBeenCalledWith("some-value");     
});
```

Both options have their valid uses.